# rank discord.js using mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I wanted to do a rank for my discord bot I tried so but gave the error "can not read property 'map' of undefined"

```js
var dados = require("../create-table");
const mysql = require('mysql');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'myhost',
  port     : '3306',
  user     : 'myuser
  password : 'mypassword',
  database : 'mydatabase',
  charset : 'utf8mb4'
});

exports.run = (client, message, args)  => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM guildn WHERE id = '${message.guild.id}'`, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Error1');
        }
        if (result.length){
            connection.query(`SELECT * FROM level WHERE guild = '${message.guild.id}'`, function (err, result2) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log('Error1');
                }
                var sla = result2.xp.map(function(a){

                })
                sla.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a - b;
                });
                console.log(sla)
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I used the google translator to make this post, so if I have any errors in the translation, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving

> "can not read property 'map' of undefined"

means that in this function here

`var sla = result2.xp.map(function(a){})`

`result2.xp` is undefined.

This usually means that it doesn't exist, mysql can't find it, but based off you code, maybe you didn't `insert` or `create` the `table` correctly? It appears to be missing a `result2.xp` value, which is leading to the issue. You should check your database and its values that will be where the error is located.

Edit: based on the comment that `result2` is an array. You should loop through the array, get the xp values and store them in another array then sort through it.

Comment: if I put the result2 [0] .xp does not appear indifined, but this just gets the 1 result and so I tried using resul2.xp to get all the results and sort

Comment: But the array itself doesn't have the property `.xp` only the values in the array do right?

Answer (score 0):

As @RaymondZhang pointed out in his answer, your error is occurring from this line:

```
var sla = result2.xp.map(function(a) { ... })
```

In your comments to that answer, you said `result2[0].xp` is not undefined, *a.k.a.* that is defined, which makes me think `result2` is an array which looks something like this:

```
[
    { xp: <string1, object1, or function1> },
    { xp: <string2, object2, of function2> },
    ...
]
```

If this is true, you are probably looking for a `map` function like this:

```
var sla = result2.map(function(a) {
    return a.xp;
});
```

You can simplify this to:

```
var sla = result2.map(a => a.xp);
```

Putting this back in your code, here is what your original code would look like:

```
... initialize variables
exports.run = (client, message, args)  => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM guildn WHERE id = '${message.guild.id}'`, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Error1');
        }
        if (result.length){
            connection.query(`SELECT * FROM level WHERE guild = '${message.guild.id}'`, function (err, result2) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log('Error1');
                }
                var sla = result2.map(function(a) {
                    return a.xp;
                });
                sla.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a - b;
                });
                console.log(sla)
            });
        }
    });
}
```